# No valid report source is available- crystal reports

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have created a report using crystal reports. I am using visual studio 2010. The problem occurs when I try to go to another page. When I try to navigate to page 2 or last page the error No valid report source is available appears on the screen. Does anyone have any idea what I need to do? Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2):

Store you report in Session and then give report source from session on page post back

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = (ReportDocument)Session["Report"];
                CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

               // throw;
            } 
        }

    }
    protected void CrystalReportViewer1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
        rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("Reports\\BalanceReportNew\\BalanceReport.rpt"));
        rptDoc.SetDataSource(ReportData());
        Session["Report"] = rptDoc;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
    }
    public DataTable ReportData()
    {
        string ClassName = ddlClass.SelectedValue;
        string Division = ddlDivison.SelectedValue;
        string Subject = ddlSubjects.SelectedValue;
        DataTable ReportData = objRpt.getReportData(ClassName, Division, Subject);
        return ReportData;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should solve your issue:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //whatever you do when the page is loaded for the first time
            //this could even be bindReport();
        }
        else
        {
            bindReport();
        }
    }

public void bindReport()
    {
        ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
        dsSample ds = new dsSample(); // .xsd file name
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        // Just set the name of data table
        dt.TableName = "Crystal Report Example";
        dt = getMostDialledNumbers(); //This function populates the DataTable
        ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt, true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
        // Your .rpt file path will be below
        rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("mostDialledNumbers.rpt"));
        //set dataset to the report viewer.
        rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
        CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        //in case you have an UpdatePanel in your page, it needs to be updated
        UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the solution in this thread:

[No Valid report source is available](https://forums.asp.net/p/1709350/4548570.aspx/1?No+Valid+report+source+is+available)

From what it says, you should be able to make it work by providing ConnectionInfo and ReportSource in the code.

Answer (score 1):

## #Simple Solution

I have just Solved this problem  using CrystalReportViewer **Navigate Event**

in View report Button  i have saved report document in a session

```
  Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   ' -- the ds is dataset variable containing data to be displayed in the report

    rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds)
    Session.Add("rptdoc", rptDoc)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc

    End Sub
```

then in Navigate event of CrystalReportViewer i set the CrystalReportViewer data source to the Session

```
Protected Sub j(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As CrystalDecisions.Web.NavigateEventArgs) Handles CrystalReportViewer1.Navigate

    rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = session("rptdoc")

End Sub
```

So each time  before you  navigate to another page in the report , CrystalReportViewer data source is set to the report  document saved in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Well its not a big problem you just need to create session of your data source. Then pass it on page load. All crystal report function will work properly.

If you need any further help or code, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Răzvan Panda. 
Full code is given here.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){ 
    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument report =
                            new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();

                        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
                        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();

                        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                        Tables CrTables;
                        report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Monthly/CrMonthly.rpt"));

                        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server4Crystal"].ToString();//[SQL SERVER NAME]
                        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database4Crystal"].ToString();//[DATABASE NAME]

                        crConnectionInfo.UserID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["User4Crystal"].ToString();//[DB USER NAME]
                        crConnectionInfo.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password4Crystal"].ToString(); //[DB PASSWORD]

    //LOOP THROUGH EACH TABLE & PROVIDE LOGIN CREDENTIALS
                        CrTables = report.Database.Tables;
                        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
                        {
                            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
                        }

    //PROVIDE PARAMETERS TO CRYSTAL REPORT, IF REQUIRED.
                        ParameterField paramField = new ParameterField();
                        ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
                        ParameterDiscreteValue paramDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

                        paramField.Name = "PARAMETER_NAME";
                        paramDiscreteValue.Value = "PARAMETER_VALUE";
                        paramField.CurrentValues.Add(paramDiscreteValue);
                        paramFields.Add(paramField);
    //ADD MORE PARAMETERS, IF REQUIRED....


                        StoreMonthlyViewer.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
                        StoreMonthlyViewer.ReportSource = report;
    //FINALLY REFRESH REPORT
                        StoreMonthlyViewer.RefreshReport();
                        StoreMonthlyViewer.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answers kind of. Store the ReportDocument in a session (or something) and set the ReportSource.

Example:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
          if (Session["ReportSource"] != null)
          {
             CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = (ReportDocument) Session["ReportSource"];
          }
          else
          {
             ReportDocument reportDocument = new ReportDocument();
             reportDocument.Load("MyReport.rpt");
             CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportDocument;
             Session["ReportSource"] = reportDocument;
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try looking for some parameter that your report does not contain

usually it happens when you insert some parameter in code and your report does not contain that parameter